# Pandas subsetting returing different results to numpy

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to subset a `pandas dataframe` using two conditions. However, I am not getting the same results as when done with `numpy`. What am I doing wrong?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(20,120,101)
y = np.linspace(-45,25,101)

xs,ys = np.meshgrid(x,y)

idx = (xs >=100) & (ys >= 0)

plt.scatter(xs,ys,s=2,c='b')
plt.scatter(xs[idx],ys[idx],s=2,c='r')
```

[image]

I need to remove the red block from my dataset, which I can do with `numpy` by using:

```
plt.scatter(xs[~idx],ys[~idx],s=2,c='b')
```

[image]

How do I replicate this with a `pandas dataframe`?

I've tried using the same logic as I used above:

```
data = {'x':x,'y':y}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

mask = (df.x >=100) & (df.y >= 0)
df2 = df[~mask]
```

I've also tried using `loc`:

```
df.loc[(df.x >=100) & (df.y >= 0),['x','y']] = np.nan
```

Both of these methods give the following result:

[image]

How do I replicate the results from `numpy`?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't obtain the same result because you didn't create all the couple of coordinates before passing them to pandas. Here is a quick solution:

```
data = {'x':xs.flatten(),'y':ys.flatten()}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
mask = (df.x >=100) & (df.y >= 0)
df2 = df[~mask]
plt.scatter(df2.x,df2.y,s=2,c='b')
```

Flatten reshape your arrays to only have one dimension so that they can be used to construct a DF containing couple of coordinates and not lists.

Output:

[image: Output]

### Edit: Same result but with dataframe containing x and y

1. Split the df in chunks

```
data_x = np.linspace(20,120,101)
data_y = np.linspace(-45,25,101)
dataframe = pd.DataFrame({'x':data_x,'y':data_y})
chunk_size = 25
dfs = [dataframe[i:i+chunk_size] for i in range(0,dataframe.shape[0],chunk_size)]
```

2. Define the function that will give you the points you are interested in. Two loops because you need to get every configuration of x and y values

```
def generatorPoints(dfs):
    for i in range(len(dfs)):
        x = dfs[i].x
        for j in range(len(dfs)):
            y = dfs[j].y
            xs, ys = np.meshgrid(x,y)
            idx = (xs >=100) & (ys >= 0)
            yield xs[~idx], ys[~idx]

x, y = [], []
for xs, ys in generatorPoints(dfs):
    x.extend(xs), y.extend(ys)

plt.scatter(x,y,s=2,c='b')
```

This gives the same result as the previous code. There is certainly place to make some optimization but this is a start for your request :).

Comment: Thanks for your answer it makes sense but when I made `df` I used the original `x` and `y` (which are already a single dimension). I want to try avoid having to meshgrid the data first as the dataset I will be working with is quite large so I'll run into memory issues. Do you have any ideas on how to get around this?

Comment: @Jetman I updated my answer to give you an idea on how to do what you want, as I said in the edit there is place to optimization in time and memory usage I think but it's a good start.

Comment: Thank you very much, I really appreciate it

Comment: @Jetman: you're welcome, I improved it a little with fewer operations and generator instead of function which is pretty much the same thing but the code is less verbose I believe.